# auto inrement in the foregin key of a mysql database tabel doesen't work

Tags: mysql

this is the error :

Query error:

> #1833 - Cannot change column 'id_utente': used in a foreign key constraint 'effettua_ibfk_2' of table 'u205688162_royalartx.effettua'

this is the table query :

```
CREATE TABLE utente
(
  nome VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
  password VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
  id_utente INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id_utente)
);
```

this is the query for adding auto increment for id_utente in utente table:

```
ALTER TABLE `utente` CHANGE `id_utente` `id_utente` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Comment: Like the error says: you can't alter a column which is used in foreign keys (here the table effettua). This is a technical limitation of MySQL.

Comment: both sides of a foreign key need to have the same datatype, which makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

To do that you need first to disable Forign keys change bioth tables and and then eneable it again see example

> ```
> CREATE TABLE utente
> (
>   nome VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
>   email VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
>   password VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
>   id_utente INT NOT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (id_utente)
> );
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE effettua (effettua_id int,
>     FOREIGN KEY (effettua_id) REFERENCES utente(id_utente) )
> ```

> ```
> ALTER TABLE `utente` CHANGE `id_utente` `id_utente` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
> ```
>
> ```
> Cannot change column 'id_utente': used in a foreign key constraint 'effettua_ibfk_1' of table 'db_1029511369.effettua'
> ```

> ```
> SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
> ```

> ```
> ALTER TABLE `utente` CHANGE `id_utente` `id_utente` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
> ```

> ```
> ALTER TABLE `effettua` CHANGE effettua_id  effettua_id INT(11)
> ```

> ```
> SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ab1b444da666c9c0b68c733138214d71)*